# Is there a wiki processor for Trac to format and colour Python tracebacks?

Tags: python, syntax, trac

Understandably many of the tickets we file in Trac contain tracebacks. It would be excellent if these were nicely formatted and syntax highlighted.

I've conducted a cursory Google search for a Python traceback wiki processor and have not found any quick hits.

I'm happy to roll my own if anyone can recommend a traceback formatter (stand alone or embedded in an open source project) that outputs HTML/reStructuredText/etc.

Comment: I just wish Python backtraces weren't upside-down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pygments](http://pygments.org/languages/) has support for syntax-coloring Python tracebacks, and there's a [trac plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracPygmentsPlugin), but the wiki page claims Trac 0.11 supports Pygments natively.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you need that patch. You could specify the shortcode mapping in the [trac.ini](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracIni#mimeviewer-section), but you can also (at least in trac 0.12) just use the mime type directly:

```
{{{
#!text/x-python-traceback
<traceback>
}}}
```

See more at http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSyntaxColoring.  x-python-traceback isn't in the list there, but you'll get an error previewing if trac can't handle it and it WorkedForMe.

Answer (score 2):

Trac 0.11 supports Pygments but doesn't expose the pytb formatting type. Here's a patch against Trac 0.11.3 to add support for Python tracebacks.

```
diff -r 5a0c5e3255b4 mimeview/api.py
--- a/mimeview/api.py   Tue Aug 11 11:33:45 2009 +1000
+++ b/mimeview/api.py   Mon Aug 24 15:13:34 2009 +1000
@@ -348,6 +348,7 @@
     'text/x-perl':            ['pl', 'pm', 'PL', 'perl'],
     'text/x-php':             ['php', 'php3', 'php4'],
     'text/x-python':          ['py', 'python'],
+    'text/x-python-traceback':['pytb'],
     'text/x-pyrex':           ['pyx'],
     'text/x-ruby':            ['rb', 'ruby'],
     'text/x-scheme':          ['scm'],
```

Comment: With the latest Trac the added line should read `'text/x-python-traceback': 'pytb',`.